# git show-branch and trying to fix / figure out what is going on

Tags: git

A git noob (or maybe used it a while in a very simple way) and sorry if this question is all over the place. I have the following when I run show-branch. I am trying to figure out exactly what is going on.

I have read through http://www.gitguys.com/topics/git-show-branch-to-see-branches-and-their-commits/ but still have a few questions.

- What is the status of the m-development -> m-development~5 commits? According to gitguys, they have been merged; does this mean merged into master?
- For m-development - m-development~5, they have a +; on gitguys, it says that this means that `Commit is in the branch`  and that a `-` means that a `Commit is in the branch as a merge`. Regarding `+`, does this mean that is in master or not? If yes, I'm pretty sure it was merged in; if it were merged into master, shouldn't it be showing as `*` in the master column?

thx for any help

```
Thu Jul 25$ git show-branch
* [master] tmp merge
 ! [m-development] Adding comments view controller
--
-  [master] tmp merge
*  [master^2] updated with some debug and logged YES -> NO
*  [master^] project updates
*  [master~2] updated name
*  [master~3] updated here
*  [master~4] updated for is_liked values
*  [master~5] updated with message saving
*  [master~6] updated here
*  [master~7] updated with 401 instead of 200; explicit -X POST on curl calls
*  [master~8] updated
*  [master~9] initial checkin
 + [m-development] Adding comments view controller
 + [m-development^] Adding isFavorited / isLiked fields, filling in with initializers
 + [m-development~2] Adding favorite / unfavorite functionality
 + [m-development~3] Hooking up HTTP call for password reset
 + [m-development~4] Implementing login and signup
 + [m-development~5] Stubbing profile view controller
*+ [master~10] Updating authentication view controllers
Thu Jul 25$
```

Comment: What are you trying to figure out by using `git show-branch`? If `m-development` was merged into `master`?

Comment: `git show-branch` isn't something I use every day. If you're just trying to get an overview of your repo's history and current state you may want to try something like `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer regarding `show-branch`

Ok, this is what's going on with your `show-branch` output. The thing you need to understand about it is that it represents a table, with each column representing a branch, and each row representing a commit. Therefore, each cell of the table represents whether or not a commit exists in a branch.

The original poster asks:

> What is the status of the `m-development` [to] `m-development~5` commits? According to gitguys, they have been merged; does this mean merged into master?

If the rows representing commits of `m-development` have a non-space character in the column for `master`, then `master` contains those commits, and therefore the branch has been merged into `master`. In such a case, the `show-branch` output would look like the following (abbreviated to relevant parts):

```
*  [master~8]
*  [master~9]
*+ [m-development]
```

The output of `show-branch` seems to stop when it finds a commit shared by all branches passed as references, or all local branches if no arguments are passed; in the case that no common commits are found, it seems to just output all commits for the branches.

So in the example above, `show-branch` finds that the tip/`head` commit of `m-development` is contained by `master`, and thus you can conclude that the entire `m-development` branch has been merged into `master`.

However, this is not what your output looks like. Your output shows a blank space in the `master` column for all the rows/commits of `m-deveopment` (again abbreviated for clarity):

```bash
* [master]
 ! [m-development]
--
# skip some output of master for this example
*  [master~8]
*  [master~9]
 + [m-development]
 + [m-development^]
 + [m-development~2]
 + [m-development~3]
 + [m-development~4]
 + [m-development~5]
*+ [master~10]
```

According to the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `show-branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show-branch.html#_output) (emphasis mine):

> If a commit is on the `I-th` branch, the `I-th` indentation character shows a `+` sign; ***otherwise it shows a space***.

Therefore, from your output, we can conclude that the commits in `m-development` haven't been merged into `master`.

### Answer regarding other methods to find merge status of branches

This doesn't answer the question of what `git show-branch` is showing you (I can explain that later), but if all you want to do is figure out if the commits of `m-development` have been merged into `master`, you can simply do

```
git log --oneline master..m-development
```

That will show you all commits that exist in `m-development` that don't also exist in `master` yet. If the command returns empty, then all commits in `m-development` also exist in `master` already.

If you want to know if `m-development` has been merged into `master`, you can also do

```
git branch --merged master
```

If you see `m-development` in the output, that means it was merged into `master`.

Comment: thx for answering my vague question :-) the git log statement helps and will try to get further with this.